# Multiple imputation to part of a dataset

Tags: stata, convergence, multiple-imputation

I am working with a survey dataset which contains hundreds of variables. The item-missing data rate ranges from 0.2% to 10%. In order to retain study units with missing values and to maintain a reasonable statistical power for my analyses, I attempted to do multiple imputation using sequential regression (chained equations) in Stata. However, with all the several variables with missing items in the equations, the models could never attain convergence. I spent days re-specifying  the equations and the options within the equations  but all in vain. In the end, I simplified the equations by selecting only variables with high item-missing  data rates and variables which apply to all study units in the dataset. This time I succeeded in multiply imputing the data.

However, I have two questions.

1. Since I did multiple imputation using only some of the variables in the dataset, there are still variables with missing values (though small). Is it acceptable to still have variables with missing values while analyzing multiply-imputed data?
2. I am also planning to do sub-population analysis. However, due to the convergence problem I stated earlier, variables pertaining only to sub-populations are excluded from the multiple imputation I did. Is it acceptable to do a separate multiple imputation to the sub-population of interest?

Comment: What kind of convergence?  IIRC with MI you want convergence in distribution

Comment: Yes, I want convergence in distribution (i.e., I want to check the stationarity of each chain by the end of the pre-specified burn-in period) before imputing data.